# Problem PHP with Django, Take PHP like plain text

Tags: python, php, django, text

I have this code

```
{% for h in lineas %}
            <tr>
              <?php> $hola=4 </?>
              <th scope="col"><a onclick="restar()">{{h}}</th>                
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

but in the navigator i see the PHP code like Plain text:

$hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4 $hola=4

i cant find the problem. Can you help me please?

Comment: It will *not* interpret the PHP code: it simply will render the Django template and send that as a response to the client.

Comment: sry i am noob in django, but i am using the render method in the view, is thath the problem?

 ``` 
def Home(request):
    horaInicio=8
    horaFin=20
    lineas=[]
    i=horaInicio
    while i < horaFin:
        lineas.append(i)
        i=i+1

  datos={"cant_motos": 7, "horaInicio": 8, "lineas":lineas}
   
    return  render(request,"home.php",datos)

 ```

Comment: Django is python...why do you expect it to run php? Amd why do you want to?? Whatever you want to write with the php code, you should just write it in python instead

Comment: i maked the code in PHP and is working. Tank you.